# End Date in Date Range

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

This question has been asked multiple times. But my problem is bit different. I want to create a pandas dataframe with date range which includes start date and end date. The code I'm using is the following:

```
pd.date_range(start_date, end_date, freq=pd.tseries.offsets.Dateoffset(months=period))
```

Here `period` is dynamic. So, it can be 1, 3, 4, 6 or 12. We also know `pd.date_range` does not include end dates. I also don't want to append the end date, as my frequency of period will be affected. So, if my date range is `01-02-2020` and `01-12-2021`. And the frequency is 3 months, then the series will end at `01-11-2021`. If I add the end date at the end, then there's 1 month difference between last date and end date.

```
DatetimeIndex(['2020-02-01', '2020-05-01', '2020-08-01', '2020-11-01',
               '2021-02-01', '2021-05-01', '2021-08-01', '2021-11-01'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='<DateOffset: months=3>')
```

My question is how to create the date range series such that it includes extreme values and accommodate the dynamic frequencies.

Thanks!

Comment: `pandas` docs say that the end date is included where possible. https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.date_range.html

Comment: The first few examples on the docs page linked above do show the end date. It's not entirely clear what you're asking for, if the range would include the end date it will be included. If you the periods selected for the range wouldn't include the end date, then there's no way to add it without it no longer conforming to the date range. Can you provide a [mcve] with _code_ for what you've actually tried and and what specifically is wrong with your current output?

Comment: @G.Anderson: I'm not looking for an answer using `date_range` command. Any other python option will do. I just can't think or find any other option. Thanks!

Comment: @BallpointBen: The examples are simplest of problems. In the question you can see I didn't get the end date.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the end date is not provided, it means that the difference between the last provided date and the end date is less than the period. So simply add `end_date` to the end of the `DatetimeIndex` object returned by `date_range`.

```
start_date=pd.to_datetime("01-02-2020", dayfirst=True)
end_date=pd.to_datetime("01-12-2021", dayfirst=True)
period=3
x=pd.date_range(start_date, end_date, freq=pd.DateOffset(months=period))

if x[len(x)-1].date != end_date.date:
    x=np.append(x.date, end_date.date())

print(x)

[datetime.date(2020, 2, 1) datetime.date(2020, 5, 1)
 datetime.date(2020, 8, 1) datetime.date(2020, 11, 1)
 datetime.date(2021, 2, 1) datetime.date(2021, 5, 1)
 datetime.date(2021, 8, 1) datetime.date(2021, 11, 1)
 datetime.date(2021, 12, 1)]
```

Comment: Thanks! I was doing this only. But thought if there's some more pythonic way of doing it. It seems there are none.